# И еще об ударениях

Tags: фонетика

Как правильно: "плАто" или "платО"? Если это слово испанского происхождения, то ударение на А - "плАто" (от "el plato" - "плита, блюдо, равнина"). Но говорят и так, и так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В орфоэпическом словаре платО.

Answer (score 0):

ПлатО, с ударением на 2 слоге.